# To check a checkbox?

Tags: verb, technical-terminology

What is the verb for checking a typical checkbox on a computer?

`auswählen`?

Something like `ankreuzen`, but for a checkbox.

Comment: "auswählen" is usually fine, I'd say.

Comment: @Annatar: I'm not convinced, since this would in the stricter sense apply to radio buttons, and therefore at least leaves open, whether other options are selectable in addition.

Comment: @guidot And what is so bad about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a checkbox offers an option:

> check: *aktivieren*
>
> uncheck: *deaktivieren*

[image]

Comment: Right!! I knew there was something basic I forgot, thanks!

Comment: Note however, that *aktivieren/deaktivieren* makes sense (and would be understandable) only when speaking of a form on a computer screen. Setting tickmarks in a paper form would never be called *aktivieren*. Moreover, you would not use *aktivieren* in ordinary, everyday language even for computer forms. You would probably use it if you are a programmer or websdesigner or so used to special vocabulary in your business.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Zum einen bezieht sich die Frage auf den Computer, zum anderen halte ich Aussagen wie _»Hast du die Röntgenblick-Option aktiviert?«_ nicht für sonderlich abwegig.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I asked explicitly about computers... and I think outside of computer-professionals environments it's also accepted / perfectly understandable (when using it to address computer checkboxes, of course).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a single verb, but *unter/bei ... ein Häkchen setzen* is the most specific wording for checkboxes. *Auswählen* is fine, too, but more general. *Aktivieren* is even more general and sounds a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 2):

That could be `ankreuzen` or `anhaken`.

Comment: "Anhaken" habe ich noch nie gehört. In welcher Gegend ist das in Gebrauch?

Comment: Ich kenn's, aber ich könnte nicht sagen, dass es auf eine bestimmte Gegend beschränkt wäre.

Comment: @dirkt: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anhaken), Bedeutung 2, kennt es auch. Es ist identisch zu *ankreuzen* gebildet.

Comment: @guidot: Es ist offensichtlich, wie es gebildet wird, und ich bzweifle auch nicht, dass es es gibt, aber ich (Raum Frankfurt/Main) habe es trotzdem noch nie gehört. Deshalb die Frage nach der Gegend/den Gegenden, wo es üblich ist.

Comment: @dirkt: Warum dann ein Kommentar statt einer eigenen Frage?

Comment: @guidot: Ich wollte auch keine wissenschaftliche Abhandlung mit genauer Gebietsanalyse und Karte dazu (so wichtig ist es auch nicht), sondern einfach wissen, woher PhilMasterG es kennt. Und außerdem gibt es dem Fragesteller einen Hinweis, daß "anhaken" nicht überall in Deutschland verwendet wird, und "ankreuzen" vielleicht besser ist. Deshalb hier als Kommentar. (Und eigentlich wollte ich auch keine Rechtfertigungsdiskussion anzetteln.)

Comment: Hier in Österreich ist es zumindest sehr gegenwärtig, mag aber natürlich sein, dass es in Deutschland anders ist, danke für den Einwand.